# Importing CSV Date into phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, date, csv, import, phpmyadmin

I need to import some data into phpMyAdmin. This works well, except for dates. This is my data :

```
1,1,"","MICROSCOPIO 40X - 600X","","SCOLAR SL8IM","SMS087008",01/02/2001,258.23,,,5,4,2,"",14,,"",,,
2,2,"","MICROSCOPIO 40X - 600X","","SCOLAR SL8IM","SMS086980",01/02/2001,258.23,,,1,,2,"",14,,"",,,
```

As you can see, I'm trying to import `01/02/2001`, but it won't work.
I tried using 'Import -> Format = CSV -> Import' with these delimiters :

[image]
but dates are always stored like '0000-00-00'. Changing the date format doesn't solve the problem, as I tried to set it to '%d/%m/%Y' but the issue persists. It also doesn't work if I add a quote before and after the date, like SQL Syntax requests.
Do you know how to solve it? I wouldn't like to insert manually every date because I've got 2160 lines to import. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider running MySQL's [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) command (which you can run in a query window in phpMyAdmin) using a user-defined variable to re-format the date column. Do note this is a MySQL specific command and hence independent of phpMyAdmin.

Specifically, since you are importing into 21 columns, adjust the date at column 8 according to format MM/DD/YYYY. Of course, switch `%m` and `%d` if you are a *dayfirst* country (i.e., non-US). Also, adjust *col#* names to actual table fields.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/my_file.csv.' 
INTO my_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, @var1, col9, col10, col11, 
  col12, col13, col14, col15, col16, col17, col18, col19, col20, col21) 
SET col8 = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

1. Open your csv in an excel viewer like MS Excel or Libre Calc.
2. Format your date column (Click Format -> cell) and convert the date format to YYYY-MM-DD
   [image: Format Date]
3. Once our whole row represents the date like `2001-12-31`, try importing it now from phpmyadmin.

Comment: This is not working (dates are still stored ad 0000-00-00), anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you share the csv data after you changed the date format? Coz I tried and tested it on my end, hence the screenshot.